# Unsure how to add Materialize Modal window to my GS Web App

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I am creating a little Google web app for inventory management that is linked to a Google sheet that looks like this:

[image]

Here is what my web app looks like so far when I deploy it:

[image]

When I click on any of the rows, it is correctly logging to the console whether the iPad is available or not available.

My end goal is for a user to click, and if the item IS available, a modal window will pop up with some text input to change the iPad status. If it is NOT available, a different modal window will pop and the user can input text to make it available.

In reading the Materialize documentation, I am unsure as to how to have the modal window appear, since the trigger is happening within another CSS template (Tabulator)

Any advice? Here is my HTML code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <title>Inventory</title>

  <!-- FETCHING TABULATOR JS -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.5.0/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>

  <!-- FETCHING TABULATOR CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tabulator-tables@5.5.0/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Include Materialize CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

  <!-- Include Materialize JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

  <!-- LINK TO CSS STYLESHEET -->
  <?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("Styles").getContent(); ?>

</head>

<body>
  
  <!-- INVENTORY WEB APP HEADER -->
  <div class="header main-header">
    <h1>Inventory Web App (Demo)</h1>
  </div>

  <!-- TODAYS DATE -->
    <div class="header sub-header">
    <h3 id="today-date" style="font-size: 16px;"></h3>
    </div>

    <script>
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        const todayDateElement = document.getElementById("today-date");
        const today = new Date().toLocaleDateString();
        todayDateElement.textContent = today;
      });
    </script>

  <!-- COLUMNS -->
  <div class="columns">
    <!-- RADIOS -->
    <div class="column">
      <h2>Radios</h2>
      <p>This is the content for the Radios column.</p>

      <div id="radio-table"></div>
      <div id="radio-alerts"></div>

      <?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('RadioScript').getContent(); ?>

    </div>

    <!-- iPADS -->
    <div class="column">
      <h2>iPads</h2>
      <p>This is the content for the iPads column.</p>

      <div id="ipad-table"></div>
      <div id="iPad-alerts"></div>

      <script>

let iPadElements = {};

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", iPadPageLoad);

function iPadPageLoad() {
  iPadElements.alerts = document.getElementById("iPad-alerts");
  loadiPadData();
}

function loadiPadData() {
  google.script.run
  .withSuccessHandler((iPadData) => {
  const table = new Tabulator("#ipad-table", {
  height: 205, // set height of table (in CSS or here), this enables the Virtual DOM and improves render speed dramatically (can be any valid css height value)
  data: iPadData, // assign data to table
  layout: "fitColumns", // fit columns to width of table (optional)
  columns: [
  { title: "iPad", field: "iPad", width: 150 },
  {
    title: "iPad Status",
    field: "iPad Status",
    widthGrow: 1,
    cellClick: handleCellClick,
    },
    ],
    });
    })
    .withFailureHandler((err) => {})
    .getiPadData();
    }

function handleCellClick (e, cell) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains("tabulator-cell")) {
  const ipad = cell.getRow().getData().iPad;
  const status = cell.getValue();

if (status === "Available") {
  console.log("Status is available")
} else {
  console.log("Status is NOT available")
}
}};

    </script>
      
  </div>

  <!-- BADGES -->
  <div class="column">
    <h2>Badges/Keys</h2>
    <p>This is the content for the Badges column.</p>
  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `My end goal is for a user to click, and if the item IS available, a modal window will pop up with some text input to change the iPad status. If it is NOT available, a different modal window will pop and the user can input text to make it available.`. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Hi Tanaike! Right now I have a function called handleCellClick but all it does is log to the console whether the value of the Status column in that row is either "Available" or "Not Available." However, instead of just logging something to the console, I want a modal window pop up using the Materialize CSS template. The user will input text into the modal window which will then change the status in that row.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `I want a modal window pop up using the Materialize CSS template.`, I think that this can be achieved. But, about `The user will input text into the modal window which will then change the status in that row.`, in this case, how do you want to do the Spreadsheet? You want to just change the text in the table of HTML?

Comment: Hey Tanaike, ideally the text in the spreadsheet will also change, but I think i have been able to accomplish that in the past, I'm just not sure how to change the table in the HTML :)

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your expected result in this question, you want to show a dialog including a text input tag when a row in the HTML table is clicked. And, you want to retrieve the inputted text when the dialog is closed. But, in this question, you don't want to update the Spreadsheet and don't want to update the table. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: If you cannot understand my English, please tell me.

Comment: Hi Tanaike, please accept my apologies for a late response! Yes you have outlined my question correctly :)

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Please confirmit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your reply, I understood your goal for this question is as follows.

- You want to show a dialog including a text input tag when a row in the HTML table is clicked.
- You want to retrieve the inputted text when the dialog is closed.
- But, in this question, you are not required to update the Spreadsheet and also you are not required to update the table.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <title>Inventory</title>

  <!-- FETCHING TABULATOR JS -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.5.0/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>

  <!-- FETCHING TABULATOR CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tabulator-tables@5.5.0/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Include Materialize CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

  <!-- Include Materialize JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

  <!-- <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
</head>

<body>

  <!-- INVENTORY WEB APP HEADER -->
  <div class="header main-header">
    <h1>Inventory Web App (Demo)</h1>
  </div>

  <!-- TODAYS DATE -->
  <div class="header sub-header">
    <h3 id="today-date" style="font-size: 16px;"></h3>
  </div>

  <script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
      const todayDateElement = document.getElementById("today-date");
      const today = new Date().toLocaleDateString();
      todayDateElement.textContent = today;
    });
  </script>

  <!-- COLUMNS -->
  <div class="columns">
    <!-- RADIOS -->
    <div class="column">
      <h2>Radios</h2>
      <p>This is the content for the Radios column.</p>
      <div id="radio-table"></div>
      <div id="radio-alerts"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- iPADS -->
    <div class="column">
      <h2>iPads</h2>
      <p>This is the content for the iPads column.</p>
      <div id="ipad-table"></div>
      <div id="iPad-alerts"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="modal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <p>Input text</p>
      <input type="text" id="sampleText">
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <a href="#!" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-light btn">OK</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    let iPadElements = {};

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", iPadPageLoad);

    function iPadPageLoad() {
      M.Modal.init(document.getElementById("modal"), {
        onCloseEnd
      });

      iPadElements.alerts = document.getElementById("iPad-alerts");
      loadiPadData();
    }

    function onCloseEnd(modal) {
      const e = document.getElementById("sampleText");
      const value = e.value;
      console.log(value); // You can see the inputted value in the console.
    }

    function loadiPadData() {
      google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler((iPadData) => {
          const table = new Tabulator("#ipad-table", {
            height: 205,
            data: iPadData,
            layout: "fitColumns",
            columns: [{
                title: "iPad",
                field: "iPad",
                width: 150
              },
              {
                title: "iPad Status",
                field: "iPad Status",
                widthGrow: 1,
                cellClick: handleCellClick,
              },
            ],
          });
        })
        .withFailureHandler((err) => {})
        .getiPadData();
    }

    function handleCellClick(e, cell) {
      if (e.target.classList.contains("tabulator-cell")) {
        const ipad = cell.getRow().getData().iPad;
        const status = cell.getValue();
        if (status === "Available") {
          var instance = M.Modal.getInstance(document.getElementById("modal"));
          instance.open();
          console.log("Status is available")
        } else {
          console.log("Status is NOT available")
        }
      }
    }
  </script>

  </div>

  <!-- BADGES -->
  <div class="column">
    <h2>Badges/Keys</h2>
    <p>This is the content for the Badges column.</p>
  </div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

- When this modified HTML and Javascript is run, a table is opened and when you click a row of the status column, a dialog is opened. And you can see the text input tag. When you input a text and click "OK" button, you can see the inputted value in the console.